Getting the transaction revert reason in Safe when using execTransactionFromModule
I am programmatically testing transactions originated from Safe multisig in Python using execTransactionFromModule.
When Safe smart contract executes the transaction, it does not give the normal revert reason flow.

The transaction does not revert
You cannot use eth_call to extract the revert reason from a transaction
Instead you get ExecutionFromModuleFailure event log

Not getting the revert reason makes it very hard to diagnose the transactions.
Is there a way to simulate Gnosis Safe transaction execution, so that I can get a revert reason correctly?

Thanks for your question! This can be quite confusing indeed. Would you be comfortable sharing the transaction you are trying to execute, so we can better help you debug it? Also, have you tried simulating it on Tenderly so you can see the entire call stack? Please let me know  Best, Louis

I'd hope to get it working with local Anvil, as it runs the unit tests. I can do Tenderly, but even with Tenderly it is a bit tedious. Extracting a revert reason should be very simple operation to have a good developer experience and not need to resort to third party tooling.
